# How can I validate a fieldset or any other kind of group in drupal Form API?

Tags: forms

I want to create a survey witch contains a couple of questions for every group. For example: I have a group about dogs with 5 difference question (every question has 3 options) and I have a group about cats with difference quetions. Now I want to validate by group. for example making it require to answer at lease two quetions on each group. How Can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with custom code by implementing [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and then adding a custom validation function and checking for the relevant field values (I don't know anything about your form so I'm not going to write any code).

Or, you can use the [field validation](https://drupal.org/project/field_validation) module, which allows you to configure via the drupal UI, extra field validation requirements.

It is a very flexible module and a couple of its validation options are:

- Require some of several fields (in the field validation extras sub-module).
- Require at least one of several fields

There are many more options so it would be worth playing with it to see if you can achieve what you want.